# Question about date time logic in Databases and/or related Applications

Tags: sql-server, database-design

i´m not very familiar with Databases at all and still I want some data out of an ODBC Connection into Excel for some easy to refresh reports. The data I´m extracting are from an application with a SQL Server Database v8. Therefore I´m not sure if the logic behind can be applied by using SQL. I think that the application itself collects the data itself in a kind of SQL Query.

example: table 1

```
 PersID DeptID Start_Date Weighting
 101    2222   01.01.2016 0,8
 101    2222   01.03.2016 1,0
```

example: table 2

```
PersID DeptID Date       Comment
101    222    01.02.2016 Hello World
```

at the end the logic should "join" the tables into:

```
PersID DeptID Date       Comment      Weighting
101    222    01.02.2016 Hello World  0,8
```

The solution would be to give the output of 0,8 for "Weighting" as its still the same since 01.01.2016 and just changes at the beginning of 01.03.2016

Any Suggestions how to solve this issue in Excel, SQL or just some basic understanding how applications saving data in that kind of way are working are highly appreciated as im curious.

Pseudo Code in my mind is like: Determine the smallest difference between one date and a list of dates but only searching for dates which are >= the current selected date.

But shouldn't this be quite slow and demanding in bigger queries?

Comment: DeptID in table 1 is 2222 or 222. You want to link table 1 to table 2 using PersId and DeptID ??

Answer (score 0):

The usual solution I do is to select top 1... where Startdate <= ... order by startdate desc

But that only works for one record.  If you need multiple rows, I think you would need to use views or CTE's and Windowing functions.